# Java application not using dark title bars even though have implemented NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance = False

Tags: java, macos, info.plist, darkmode

I have implemented a Dark Mode for my Java application (using [flatlaf](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/)) but the title bar has light appearance even when MacOS itself it set to use Dark Mode. The possible solution is to set **NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance** to **false** in the **Info.plist** file. I have done this as part of building the appbundle (with [TheInfiniteKind fork of appbundler](https://github.com/TheInfiniteKind/appbundler)) but it is not working for me

This is the contents of the generated **Info.plist** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>SongKong</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>songkong.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.jthink.songkong</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>SongKong</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>SongKong</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>8.2</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleHelpBookFolder</key>
<string>SongKongHelp</string>
<key>CFBundleHelpBookName</key>
<string>com.jthink.songkong.Help</string>
<key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
<true/>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>sgkg</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string></string>
<key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
<string>10.7</string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string>public.app-category.music</string>
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<false/>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
<key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key>
<true/>
<key>IgnorePSN</key>
<false/>
<key>NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>JVMRuntime</key>
<string>temurin-17.jdk</string>
<key>JREPreferred</key>
<false/>
<key>JDKPreferred</key>
<false/>
<key>JVMMainClassName</key>
<string>com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong</string>
<key>JVMDebug</key>
<false/>
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
<array>
<string>mp3</string>
<string>wma</string>
<string>ogg</string>
<string>flac</string>
<string>wav</string>
<string>aif</string>
<string>aiff</string>
<string>aifc</string>
</array>
<key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
<false/>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>Music Files</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Editor</string>
</dict>
</array>
<key>LSArchitecturePriority</key>
<array>
</array>
<key>LSEnvironment</key>
<dict>
<key>LC_CTYPE</key>
<string>UTF-8</string>
</dict>
<key>JVMOptions</key>
<array>
<string>-Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog</string>
<string>-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=jdk</string>
<string>-Djava.util.logging.config.class=com.jthink.songkong.logging.StandardLogging</string>
<string>-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true</string>
<string>-Dapple.awt.brushMetalLook=true</string>
<string>-Dsun.java2d.metal=true</string>
<string>-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError</string>
</array>
<key>JVMDefaultOptions</key>
<dict>
</dict>
<key>JVMArguments</key>
<array>
</array>
<key>NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>AppleWindowTabbingMode</key>
<string>manual</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things seem to have moved on, I found this issue fixed in Java 14 - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235363

I found setting

```
-Dapple.awt.application.appearance=system
```

as an element in *JVMOptions* in the *Info.plist* worked as expected.

Comment: In case anyone else has a similar type of issue, I'll mention that it's necessary to call `System.setProperty("apple.awt.application.appearance", "system");`, as outlined [here](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/macos/).